# exclude constraint with filtered row comparison

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

The example is based on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html

Let's say I have a schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE zoo (
  cage   INTEGER,
  animal TEXT,
  is_agressive BOOLEAN,
  constraint no_different_animals_in_same_cage EXCLUDE USING gist (cage WITH =, animal WITH <>)
);
```

`no_different_animals_in_same_cage` prevents two different animals from being in the same cage. What I want is to have that constraint only if one of the animals `is_aggressive IS TRUE`. So there can be a deer with zebra in the `cage`, as long as none of the has `is_aggressive` flag set to `TRUE`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to prevent that aggressive and non aggressive animals to live in the same cage, you might wanna add `is_aggressive` to the `EXCLUDE` constraint and cast it to a type that is supported by `btree_gist`, e.g. `int4` (1 = true, 0 = false):

```
 CREATE TABLE zoo (
  cage   INTEGER,
  animal TEXT,
  is_aggressive BOOLEAN,
  CONSTRAINT no_different_animals_in_same_cage 
    EXCLUDE USING gist (cage WITH =, animal WITH <>, int4(is_aggressive) WITH <>)
);
```

This will work:

```
INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(1,'zebra',false);
INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(1,'zebra',false);
INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(1,'deer',false);

INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(2,'lion',true);
INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(2,'lion',true);
```

And this will fail:

```
INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(1,'lion',true);

ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "no_different_animals_in_same_cage"
DETAIL:  Key (cage, animal, int4(is_aggressive))=(1, lion, 1) conflicts with existing key (cage, animal, int4(is_aggressive))=(1, zebra, 0).
SQL state: 23P01
```

Note that it is still possible to insert two aggressive animals to the same cage! To prevent it you could add an `UNIQUE INDEX` to the table, so that on top of the `EXCLUDE` constraint it checks the incoming records to see if there is an aggressive animal already living in a specific cage:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX aggressive_animals_live_alone
ON zoo (cage,is_aggressive) WHERE (is_aggressive);
```

Now this will also fail:

```
INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(2,'lion',true);
INSERT INTO zoo VALUES(2,'killer bunny',true);

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "aggressive_animals_live_alone"
DETAIL:  Key (cage, is_aggressive)=(2, t) already exists.
```

If you want to perform more complex checks, I suggest you take a look at triggers.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e4d927f874eacaf71fef6a01a8a1fd1d)

As pointed out by @Arkaduisz Noster in the comments, if it is allowed for at least 1 aggressive animal to share a cage with non aggressive ones, one can add a `WHERE` clause to the `CONSTRAINT`:

```
CREATE TABLE zoo (
  cage   INTEGER,
  animal TEXT,
  is_aggressive BOOLEAN,
  CONSTRAINT no_different_animals_in_same_cage 
    EXCLUDE USING gist (cage WITH =, animal WITH <>) WHERE (is_aggressive)
);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0e5b5347afa4441aa8518f81cded3949)

Comment: Thank you @JimJones it works as expected. But, as my colleague noted, there is another solution to that problem which is just adding `WHERE` to the constraint definition:
`CONSTRAINT no_different_animals_in_same_cage EXCLUDE USING gist (cage WITH =, animal WITH <>) WHERE is_aggressive IS NOT true`
Can you please note that solution in your answer too? It seems more elegant

Comment: @ArkadiuszNoster thanks a lot for the feedback! +1 It really looks much more elegant (I wasn't aware of this syntax). Could you please show me how the create table statement would look like?

Comment: Hah, once again I was wrong. Apparently the WHERE statement applies to both inserted and existing rows, so in fact my solution doesn't work as expected following the specifiaction given by me. But it appears that our case is a bit different than the one from specification in the question, so constraint with `WHERE` was just fine - we only needed to consider rows, where the predicate was false. Anyways, here is a snippet which shows the usage of constraint with WHERE
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f7cd47dcaef6567e2d23e2529504c1af

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! It is indeed an elegant alternative if the use case applies :) In this case it is possible to have an aggressive animal sharing the cage with a non-aggressive one. for the sake of completion, I will add this option in the answer. Cheers and happy coding