# Check Constraint Equivalent to Partial Unique Index

Tags: postgresql

I have a column holding some values.  I would like to enforce uniqueness for values 1 and 2, but all other values in that column do not need to be unique.  I know how to do it with partial unique index.  I was wondering if there is a better way.  Maybe check constraint?

Comment: Perhaps an exclude constraint using btree_gist? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68772296/2275388

Comment: CHECK constraints are for checking within each row, not for checking across rows.  You can trick them into checking across rows, but then you will get race hazards, which unique indexes avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a partial unique index is the way to go. Why look for a second solution if you have a perfectly good one?